# I want to add progressbar between two activity

Tags: android, multithreading

In android application when second activity is being called from first one i want to put progressbar between two activities, so that application seems that it is in running state, and i think such thing is done through thread,help me if anyone knows this..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in second activity, what you are actually doing? Be more descriptive, and this is a site for enthusiast programmer, not for "SMS"er, so dont write SMS words like "ne1"

Comment: Acctully i want to put a progressbar in between two activities, in first activity data are shown from database and in second activity more details of selected data is shown. the main thing is progressbar between the two things so that user does not feel that app has been hanged...

Comment: see my answer, it will exactly suits your requirement. Please go through the answer and try to implement it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kartik is right, But let me add more to show Progressbar inside activity.

As you want to show Progressbar along with fetching data in background,you should implement AsyncTask in your second activity.

Here is an example:

```
 private class performBackgroundTask extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, Void>  
      {
               private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(ClassName.this);

               protected void onPreExecute()
               {
                   Dialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
                   Dialog.show();
               }

               protected void onPostExecute(Void unused)    
               {
                   try
                   {
                       if(Dialog.isShowing())
                       {
                           Dialog.dismiss();
                       }
                               // do your Display and data setting operation here
                   }
                   catch(Exception e)
                   {

                   }

            @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
            {
           // Do your background data fetching here 
               return null;   
        }
      }
```

After adding this performBackgroundTask class, you need to call **`execute()`** for the same whenever you want to execute.

Comment: It sounds silly, but since I am new to android, thanks to this answer I understood now the AsyncTask! Thank you!

Comment: @ValentinoRu Glad that my answer is helpful to you. cheers....anyway this was answered more than a year ago :)

Answer (score 3):

You must use AsyncTask or Thread for getting the details of selected data. By using this you can solve your problem of displaying progressbar between two activities..

AsyncTask basic Example : [AsyncTask](http://www.android10.org/index.php/articlesother/239-android-application-and-asynctask-basics)

```
private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    // perform long running operation operation
    return null;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPostExecute(java.lang.Object)
 */
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // execution of result of Long time consuming operation
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPreExecute()
 */
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
// Things to be done before execution of long running operation. For example showing ProgessDialog
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onProgressUpdate(Progress[])
 */
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
  // Things to be done while execution of long running operation is in progress. For example updating ProgessDialog
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In android only the main thread, also called the UI thread, can to UI operations. So, you cannot show a progress bar from a new thread.
I think the solution to your problem may to show your second activity (possibly empty), show progress dialog from onCreate() then do any heavy lifting in the activity.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just make ProgressDialog in the activity that make your calculations.

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, title, text);
```

and when your task is done close it

```
if(progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing())
      progressDialog.dismiss();
```

But be sure to show and dismiss dialog from UI thread. AsyncTask is probably the best sollution for such case